# Log4j2 SmtpAppender to include exceptions without the stack trace source code location

Tags: java, log4j2

We have a `SmtpAppender` configured with a custom `RateLimiter` filter and `ERROR` log level, everything is working as expected except for the exceptions format, they are including the source code location which we would like to remove, we add such appender programmatically to each logger after the logging facility has been initialized, example of log:

```
2019-05-03 10:39:58,871        Thread-9 ERROR s.utils.Startup - Testing error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Testing error
    at com.somepackage.SomeClass.lambda$enableEmailLogging$0(Startup.java:619) ~[classes/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
```

The `~[classes/:?]` and `[?:1.8.0_212]` are annoying to us, also; in general we would like our logging to always include the exceptions which is well accomplished in our `RollingRandomAccessFile` appender as well, but having the same problem of stack trace source code location being included, here is also a snippet of our rolling file appender:

```
<Appenders>
   <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingFile" fileName="/opt/tomcat/logs/some-webapp.log"
                                 filePattern="/opt/tomcat/logs/some-webapp.log-%d{yyMMdd-HH}"
                                 ignoreExceptions="false">
       <PatternLayout>
           <Pattern>%d{DEFAULT} %15.15t %-5p %15.15c - %m%n</Pattern>
       </PatternLayout>
       <Policies>
           <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
       </Policies>
   </RollingRandomAccessFile>
</Appenders>
```

I have looked all over for a way to accomplish this with no luck.

Comment: We are using a `PatternLayout` with the `SmtpAppender` so maybe we need to switch to another layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `PatternLayout`'s pattern from:

```
%d{DEFAULT} %15.15t %-5p %15.15c - %m%n
```

to

```
%d{DEFAULT} %15.15t %-5p %15.15c - %m%n%throwable
```

and removing the option `ignoreExceptions` from the appenders seem to accomplish what I wanted.